# Make Selenium undetectable (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha, captcha

how do i make selenium undetectable? I try to make a little experiment if i can bypass recaptcha using selenium. But google detects that it is a bot and says `Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now. For more details visit our help page.`

What i tried:

```
cool_options.add_extension('buster.crx') # Extention to solve captchas
cool_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']) #Remove "chrome is controlled by automated testsoftware"
cool_options.add_argument('window-size=1146,671') # Change window size
cool_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36') # Add useragent
```

Also i added a random wait time through every action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing this chromedriver: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: There's also a [`selenium-stealth`](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth) which can be seen as a re-implementation of JavaScript [`puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra). [Results using `selenium-stealth`](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth#selenium-with-selenium-stealth-).

Comment: At 2023 I don't think there's any better driver than ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver. Others are either not maintained or are detected.